# Firebase functions GET request with query params returns 400 error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function called `base` which runs and returns a 200 status fine with the expected payload when I do a GET via postman to: `http://localhost:5001/api-name/region/base`.

But when I add a get parameter to the URL, the request fails, i.e. `http://localhost:5001/api-name/region/base?origin=localhost`. I get a 400 Bad Request error. The interesting thing is while postman reports the 400 Bad Request almost immediately, the firebase emulator acts like it is still running the function and times out after 60s.

I have function runtime options to set the request at 300s (because it's a big query and takes a while, this works as expected too without the params), so it seems like it's not even being routed to the correct function or anywhere at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution was to update to the latest version of firebase-tools.

If using npm:
`npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`

This was a bug fixed in v9.2.1. More info here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.2.1